# How to save a POST request response as a PDF file persistently such that user may open it from outside the app later in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, post, alamofire

I'm working on an iOS application. In the app, I am using Alamofire to create a POST request that returns a raw PDF file in response. Right now, I am able to save the file and open it with `UIDocumentInteractionController`. But, I want the file to stay in User's documents folder.
Here's how I create the destination path:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in 
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Dividend Summary Report.pdf")
    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
```

Someone please tell me what's wrong with my logic and what I can do to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to check the file status if it exists then read from `documentDirectory` else download the file.

Create function like this:

```
func checkIfFileExists(urlString: String) {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let fileName = urlString
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).pdf")?.path
        print("filePath : \(String(describing: filePath))")
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
            print("File exists")
          
        } else {
            print("File doesn't exists")
            // set your download function here
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not what I need though. I am already overwriting any previous file if exists. I need a way that can save the file permanently in the storage.